# To remove blood vessel

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I want to remove the blood vessel in this images, please suggest any method and want to detect the microaneurysms (the red small dots in the images), below is my images after enhancement :

[image]

Comment: Add more details to your question:
1. what do you want to put instead of the blood vessels?
2. how do you define microaneurysms?

Comment: I can't see any red small dots, I'm afraid. Where are they? Is this image processed in any way? If so, do you have the raw image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
A = imread ('tFKeD.jpg');

C=bwlabel(A);
IM2 = imcomplement(C); % // invert the image so that your objects are 1
se = strel('diamond',3); % // Create a morphological object
BW2 = imdilate(IM2,se);  
L=bwlabel(BW2); % // Label your objects

E = regionprops(L,'area'); % // Get the respective area
Area = cell2mat(struct2cell(E)); % // Convert to a matrix
[~,largestObject] = max(Area); % // Find the one with the largest area
vessel = L==largestObject; 
imshow(vessel)
```

[image]

Comment: This method is called what?...but I want remove it...not to detect it

Comment: Yes, but that depends on your application. This gives you the location of the vessel. Now you have decide ***how*** you want to remove it. I can't do that for you. Only you know what you mean by remove.

Comment: okay...thanks for ur helped, :)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest the following approach:

1. Take a threshold on the input image and keep all the values below the threshold.
   This will generate a mask, in which the blood vessels and the microaneurysms are marked in white, and the rest is marked in black.
   The threshold value can be determined by using the image histogram. 
   From looking at the image, it seems that the threshold should be low (due to the fact that the blood vessels and the microaneurysms are relatively dark).
2. Calculate the connected components in the image using bwconncomp.
3. Perform noise cleaning on the mask from the previous stage.
   This can be done by using morphological operations (such as imclose), or by zeroing out connected components which
   are too small to be classified as microaneurysms.
4. The biggest connected component should represent the blood vessels - remove it from your mask.
   The output of this stage will be the desired result.

Comment: sorry...I can't understand the first point... how to take a threshold on the input image and keep all the values below the threshold?

Comment: Given an input image I, and a threshold T (for example, T=50), simply write: mask = I < 50;

Comment: i still cannot get...thanks for ur helped